Translate phrase from Stephen King novel
In Stephen King's novel Song of Susannah, aka Dark Tower book 6, he has the phrase:

In the Kingdom of Ago, the clocks tick... but their hands never move.

I am translating this to Latin but find some words a bit more difficult, with the usage of "ago" being particularly challenging.
Here is my first attempt:

In Imperio Agonis, Horologia crepitant… sed manūs eorum nec unquam movent.

To initially keep it simple, I treated "ago" like a third declension noun as though it was a borrowed word. In addition to that, I also found "tick" difficult and wasn't sure if nec unquam was the right way to express "never" in this usage.
I usually prefer classical for translations, however in this case because I am trying to specifically speak about mechanical clocks I'm looking for Neo-Latin to capture that.
Edit:
I made another attempt based on comments and to make the first part closer to the original:

In Regno Praeteritorum, Horologia Crepitant… sed Manūs Eorum Numquam Movent


I don't think clocks ticked in antiquity, but I'm certain someone from the recent centuries must have described the ticking of a clock in Latin somewhere.

sed...nec unquam seems weird to me. I think you might be better with just numquam, at least in this construction. I haven't checked PHI for comparisons yet, though. Are you modeling it off something?

Smith and Hall had an entry using crepitat but the source was listed as a question market.
tick (v.): the clock t.s, *horologium in numerum crepitat (?): to t. off names, perh. *puncto nomina notare.

Regarding nec unquam, I was basing it off examples in the dictionary. Numquam alone looks a lot better to me, though.

I wonder if you might have better luck with the image of a sundial: "the sun traverses the sky, but the shadows on the sundial never follow"?

How about a clepsydra with droplets falling down but the water level remaining constant? That should come with ample options for vocabulary.

Hmm... interesting. I think it strays too far from the modern conception of clocks for me, but I'm okay with this being more neo-Latin in order to keep clocks. I'm going to edit my post and add an updated idea.

I'd say to add that information (that you're looking for Neo-Latin in order to keep the reference to mechanical clocks as opposed to sundials or water clocks) to the question itself.

I'm late with my reply, but updated it to be explicit that I'd like Neo-Latin so as to be specific to mechanical clocks.
